# babel not compile import keyword

Tags: javascript, babeljs

My file **es6.js** code is:

```
import app from './app.js';
console.log(app);
```

my file **app.js** code is:

```
export default {
   "userName":"booles"
}
```

I input command :

```
babel es6.js -out-file index.js
```

but **index.js** output is:

```
 'use strict';
 var _app = require('./app.js');
 var _app2 = _interopRequireDefault(_app);
 function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj :     { default: obj }; }
 console.log(_app2.default);
```

why the 'import' not compile???

Comment: I don't see the issue here? The `import` got transpiled into a CommonJS `require`, that's the expected result. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I hope the **index.js** can run in the browser.But browser is not support `require('./app.js')`.Is not because of the babel is not compiled import？？

Comment: You need to use Webpack or Browserify to bundle your modules. Babel by itself only converts the syntax, it doesn't handle linking everything up as far as I know.